# Javascript sorting based on key of a nested array

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON where i have to sort based on key "name" first and only if names are same then sort on the key "date" with the latest date on first.
My JSON-

```
var jsonResp=[{

    "List": [{
        "listName": {
            "name": "abc ",
            "age": "32 ",           
            "detailInformation": {              
                "date": "Nov 12, 2015"              
            },          
        },

    }, 
    {
        "listName": {
            "name": "abc ",
            "age": "32 ",           
            "detailInformation": {              
                "date": "Dec 12, 2016"              
            },          
        },
    }
}]
```

Like this, I have three objects in jsonResp array and each object has

To sort the above JSON based on the above mentioned requirement, I have written the JS-

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(jsonResp, function(value,key){ 
    var newList = value.List;   
        if(newList.length > 1){
            newList.sort(function(a, b) {

                if (a.listName.name==b.listName.name){
                 return (b.listName.detailInformation.date - a.listName.detailInformation.date);
                } else {
                 return (a.listName.name-b.listName.name);
                }        
            }); 
        }

});
```

With the above js, i am getting undefined and also i cannot see my array sorted.Can anyone let me know where am i going wrong and how to display the new sorted array.Much appreciated.Thanks in advance!
Please note, the JSON i have used is just for reference.Just wanted to be sure if i am targetting the keys properly as the javascript inbuilt sort functionality works only with arrays.

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything, thus `undefined`

Comment: it would be easier if you have the date in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Comment: `sort` mutates the original array though so you may already have it sorted. Have you checked `jsonResp` after doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this :

```js
var jsonResp = [{
  "List": [{
    "listName": {
      "name": "pqr ",
      "age": "32 ",
      "detailInformation": {
        "date": "Nov 12, 2015"
      },
      "flag": true
    },

  }, {
    "listName": {
      "name": "abc ",
      "age": "32 ",
      "detailInformation": {
        "date": "Dec 12, 2016"
      },
      "flag": true
    },
  }, {
    "listName": {
      "name": "abc ",
      "age": "32 ",
      "detailInformation": {
        "date": "Nov 12, 2015"
      },
      "flag": true
    },

  }, {
    "listName": {
      "name": "pqr ",
      "age": "32 ",
      "detailInformation": {
        "date": "Nov 12, 2015"
      },
      "flag": false
    },

  }, {
    "listName": {
      "name": "abc ",
      "age": "32 ",
      "detailInformation": {
        "date": "Dec 12, 2016"
      },
      "flag": false
    },
  }, {
    "listName": {
      "name": "abc ",
      "age": "32 ",
      "detailInformation": {
        "date": "Nov 12, 2015"
      },
      "flag": false
    },

  }]
}];

Array.prototype.forEach.call(jsonResp, function(value, key) {
  var newList = value.List;
  if (newList.length > 1) {
    newList = newList.sort(function(a, b) {
      var x, y;
      if (a.listName.name == b.listName.name) {
        x = b.listName.detailInformation.date.trim();
        y = a.listName.detailInformation.date.trim();
      } else {
        x = a.listName.name.trim();
        y = b.listName.name.trim();
      }
      if (x > y) return 1;
      else if (x < y) return -1;
      else return 0;
    });
    newList = newList.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a.listName.flag) return -1;
      else if (b.listName.flag) return 1;
      else return 0;
    });
    
    for (var i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) {
      console.log(newList[i].listName.name + newList[i].listName.flag + " "+ newList[i].listName.detailInformation.date);
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks!Just wanted to cross check if i need to create an empty array and push the new items to it as right now its getting printed in console. would like the sorted item from the JSON to appear in the page.

Comment: No you dont need any new array. The jsonResp itself got sorted as sort method is a mutable method.

Comment: Hi, i have a flag inside listName object which is false for the first object i.e 'listName' and true for other two objects.Whenever the flag value is true, the listName having values true appears.The sorting functionality writtena bove is working fine but i need to sort the true and false sorting separately.Any idea on that?

Comment: Check the updated answer. I have sorted on flag after sorting on name/date. That sorts both, true and false flagged values.

Comment: I am using two for loops and checking for flag and writing the sort logic inside.Its  just that I have to write it twice.Let me know if we have any better way.

Comment: I guess this answer solves your problem. Code performance based question can be asked here : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Much appreciated!

Comment: I am new here and do not have enough points to close.I have voted you though.Let me know if this is helpful.